# Did Dukes, Counts, Barons, etc. have courts similar to a King/Emperor?

Tags: middle-ages, renaissance, titles, enlightenment

So this question is somewhat based on my thoughts from playing Crusader Kings. But how historically accurate was it for anybody besides a King/Emperor to have a court system of courtiers? Did a Count meet with the Kings court, then when he got done with his business for the day/week/month there, go back to his land holdings and deal with his lords subordinate to him there? Did he have subordinate barons, baronets, courtiers (and the likewise hierarchy for anybody else)? Did they have influence in his decisions he made at the Kings court? Or did they just have advisors they were "on the payroll" but had no influence in how they dealt with their titles?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: I think you'll have to name a country (and possibly a tighter date range) as the relationship between the monarch and his nobles (and between the nobles and their followers) varied across Europe and also across the medieval period.

Comment: Keep in mind that even in CK, the majority of your "court" is not made up of subordinate nobles, but of title-less hangers-on. Even the lowest lord would have "courtiers" in the persons of his family and those to whom he extends patronage, such as men-at-arms, performers, or physicians.

Comment: Servants at households of landed nobles were often low-ranking unlanded nobles as well. I think that's what most courtiers in the Crusader Kings games are representing: They are "employees" who perform jobs that are not important enough to be represented by any concrete game mechanics in exchange for room and board.

Comment: @SPavel Do you have any additional reading sources about these? I'm not looking for something like [The Book of the Courtier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_the_Courtier), but more like biographies of Barons, Counts, or Dukes who describe their experiences within their own personal courts.

Comment: I fail to see how this question is closed as **Too Broad**. Yes, there was considerable variety across Christendom in how feudalism was practiced; but perhaps the one unifying concept across that domain is the delegation and distribution of the legal system down the feudal vassalage hierarchy. My answer talks about the English case, only because that is what I know best; not because there will be meaningful (in terms of the question) variation across Europe and (Christian) Middle East.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, absolutely - but perhaps not quite as described in Crusader Kings. (I am unfamiliar with this game.)

First, let's make clear that a "Court" is, primarily, a "court"; the place and people where legal cases are tried. A monarch's *court* was the final *court of appeal* for all offenses against *the king's peace* - what today we term felonies and misdemeanours - and, in England prior to [Magna Carta](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Magna-Carta) at least, also the location where all offenses by *peers of the realm* were tried.

However, all of what we today term civil cases would be tried at the lowest level (ie by the lowest ranking lord or knight in the feudal hierarchy) who held jurisdiction over all parties. Thus even a lowly knight with a single manor might, a few times a year, be required to convene a [manorial court](https://www.dhi.ac.uk/conisbrough/find/manor_court.html) for hearing and deciding civil cases between his tenants.

> The manor court was the lowest court of law in England and governed those areas over which the lord of the manor had jurisdiction; it applied only to those who resided in or held lands within the manor. The court was to meet every three weeks throughout the year, although meetings could be more irregular than this. This was the court baron or manorial court, which all freeholders whose terms of tenure included suit of court and copyholders were obliged to attend. These courts dealt with copyhold land transfers, managing the open fields, settling disputes between individuals and manorial offences. ....

> Although the manor court was the lord's court, and everything was done in his name, it was usually presided over by his steward, ....

> Other officers of the court, graves, were elected annually from amongst the copyholders, one grave for each of the graveships in the manor. ... During the medieval period, graves also supervised labour services on the lord's desmesne. ....

Secondly, and related to the concept of legal appeal, the *court* system was where vassals made their petitions for relief from grievances:

- > Congress shall make no law ...; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the government for a redress of grievances. - [First Amendment, U.S. Constitution](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/first_amendment)
- > In every stage of these oppressions we have petitioned for redress in the most humble terms; our repeated petitions have been answered only by repeated injury. A prince, whose character is thus marked by every act which may define a tyrant, is unfit to be the ruler of a free people. - [U.S. Declaration of Independence](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/declare.asp)

Again, such petitions would start at the lowest level with civil jurisdiction over all parties; and possibly eventually wind their up the feudal hierarchy to the Royal Court.

Finally, under [Magna Carta](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/medieval/magframe.asp)<sup>1</sup>, the right to try offenses by *peers of the realm* was removed from the Royal Court and transferred to the nascent *House of Lords*:

- > 21. Earls and barons shall not be amerced<sup>2</sup> except through their peers, and only in accordance with the degree of the offense.
- > 39. No freemen shall be taken or imprisoned or disseised<sup>3</sup> or exiled or in any way destroyed, nor will we go upon him nor send upon him, except by the lawful judgment of his peers or by the law of the land.
- > 52. If anyone has been dispossessed or removed by us, without the legal judgment of his peers, from his lands, castles, franchises, or from his right, we will immediately restore them to him; and if a dispute arise over this, then let it be decided by the five and twenty barons of whom mention is made below in the clause for securing the peace. Moreover, for all those possessions, from which anyone has, without the lawful judgment of his peers, been disseised or removed, by our father, King Henry, or by our brother, King Richard, and which we retain in our hand (or which as possessed by others, to whom we are bound to warrant them) we shall have respite until the usual term of crusaders; excepting those things about which a plea has been raised, or an inquest made by our order, before our taking of the cross; but as soon as we return from the expedition, we will immediately grant full justice therein.

Footnotes:

1. Note that the first person plural in the quotes, ie "us" and "we", is the *royal we* and refers to King John.
2. [Amerce](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/medieval/magnadef.asp#amerce) - To impose a fine. Also to publish by fine or penalty.
3. [Disseise](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/medieval/magnadef.asp#disseise) - To dispossess or to deprive.